# Compare two CSV files against a master CSV file and merge the results into a new file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have 3 CSV files. I have one master CSV document that holds the bulk of the information I'll need down the road. But is missing data from two other CSV documents. The goal is to compare the  master document to each of the other CSVs, pull the specified data from the 2 CSVs and add that info to the rows in the master CSV. Finally writing them to a new file.

Here is what I've gotten so far, not that it works.

**inv** = is the master document, it has 99% of the information I need

**vb** = has in common 'PART CODE' with inv's '\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE', I need it's 'ON-HAND' added to inv's row

**main** = has in common 'PART CODE' with inv's '\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE', I need it's 'ON-HAND' added to inv's row

```
import csv

inv = csv.DictReader(open('ireport.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
vb = csv.DictReader(open('vb.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
main = csv.DictReader(open('main.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")

vblist = []
mainlist = []

def vbfunc(dictreader1, dictreader2):
        dictreader2 = list(dictreader2)
        for dictline1 in dictreader1:
            for dictline2 in dictreader2:
                if dictline1['PART CODE'] == dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']:
                    dictline2['VB'] = dictline1['ON-HAND']
                else:
                    dictline2['VB'] = "0" 
        vblist.append(dictline2)

def mainfunc(dictreader1, dictreader2):
        dictreader2 = list(dictreader2)
        for dictline1 in dictreader1:
            for dictline2 in dictreader2:
                if dictline1['PART CODE'] == dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']:
                    dictline2['MAIN'] = dictline1['ON-HAND']
                else:
                    dictline2['MAIN'] = "0"
        mainlist.append(dictline2)

vbfunc(vb,inv)
#mainfuc(main,inv)   #I'll get to this when the other function works

for i in vblist:
    print i['VB']  #complains of KeyError: VB
```

1st problem:

```
if dictline1['PART CODE'] == dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']:
    dictline2['VB'] = dictline1['ON-HAND']
else:
    dictline2['VB'] = "0"
```

When it's added to the list, it treats every result as "0", if I omit the else: dictline2['VB'] = "0" part, it reports as expected. But if not left in, it will later complain of KeyError: 'VB' when I try to print i['VB']

2nd problem:

```
for i in vblist:
    print i['VB']  #complains of KeyError: VB
```

As stated, complains of a KeyError. If I simply do print i, it displays that the key/value for i is there, it'll report 'VB': '0', etc.

I'm still very green to programming, been at this hours a night for a week and I've become discouraged. But not enough to give up!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  You have your inv file, which has an 'ON-HAND' column.  Am I correct in interpreting your question to mean you want to fill a 'PART CODE' column with results from either main or vb, depending on which shares the ON-HAND value with inv?

Comment: INV does *not* have an on-hand, dictline2['VB'] = dictline1['ON-HAND'] is adding a dictionary key & value to the line from INV.

Comment: If you're going to be working with tabular data, you should check out the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.  It makes merging and aligning data much easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you intended to indent the append statements so they occur for each inner loop literation:

```
    for dictline1 in dictreader1:
        for dictline2 in dictreader2:
            if dictline1['PART CODE'] == dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']:
                dictline2['VB'] = dictline1['ON-HAND']
            else:
                dictline2['VB'] = "0" 
            vblist.append(dictline2)    #indented
```

Beyond that, it's a little difficult to parse out the issue from the description you've provided.  I suggest printing a few lines at each stage to confirm that the data is indeed being handled as you expect.  For example, if you also turn dictline1 into a list you can take a small slice of each file:

```
def vbfunc(dictreader1, dictreader2):
    #iterate over 5 rows each
    dictreader1 = list(dictreader1)[:5] 
    dictreader2 = list(dictreader2)[:5]

    for dictline1 in dictreader1:
        for dictline2 in dictreader2:

            #print what's being read... 
            print '\nLines 1, 2', dictline1, dictline2
            print '\nColumns 1, 2', dictline1['PART CODE'], dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']

            if dictline1['PART CODE'] == dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']:
                dictline2['VB'] = dictline1['ON-HAND']
            else:
                dictline2['VB'] = "0" 

            #print the modified line
            print '\n New line 2', dictline2
            vblist.append(dictline2)    #indented

print '\n Modified lines ', vbList[:10] #print first 10 rows of output together
```

If you get past the above are dealing with a lot of data, you can also catch the KeyErrors specifically like so:

```
for row in vbList:
    try:
        print row['VB']
    except KeyError:
        print row
```

Comment: Indent was originally in the right place, tried as you suggested and it would complain about unintended indent at every other spot than the original.  Your sharing the [:10] to print the first # of rows is a huge help tho. Now I can see my failure happen near instantly instead of every 2 minutes.

Comment: Converting both dictlines to lists was also a good tip. Now I can call i['VB'] reliably. Still having the issue where the if then loop assigns everything to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work! It's a bit kludgy but for my purposes I think I can get this all to behave.

```
import csv

inv = csv.DictReader(open('ireport.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
vb = csv.DictReader(open('vb.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
main = csv.DictReader(open('main.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")


def vbfunc(dictreader1, dictreader2):
        dictreader2 = list(dictreader2)
        dictreader1 = list(dictreader1)
        vblist = []
        for dictline1 in dictreader1:
            for dictline2 in dictreader2:
                if dictline1['PART CODE'] == dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']:
                    dictline2['VB'] = dictline1['ON-HAND']
                else:
                    continue
        vblist.append(dictline2)
    for i in vblist:
        print i['BARCODE'],i['VB']

def mainfunc(dictreader1, dictreader2):
        dictreader2 = list(dictreader2)[:5000]
        dictreader1 = list(dictreader1)[:5000]
        mainlist = []
        for dictline1 in dictreader1:
            for dictline2 in dictreader2:
                if dictline1['PART CODE'] == dictline2['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE']:
                    dictline2['MAIN'] = dictline1['ON-HAND']
                else:
                    continue
        mainlist.append(dictline2)
    for i in mainlist:
        print i['BARCODE'],i['MAIN']


vbfunc(vb,inv)
mainfunc(main,inv)
```